# postfix and mailman. One list is working, others bounce

Tags: postfix, mailman

Running Ubuntu 16.04, mailman 2.1.24, postfix 3.1.0.

The server runs several domains. Postfix and virtual mailboxes are running well.
After much wrestling I have mailman working with one list. I then imported a list, from the previous host, and used withlist to import it. I checked that the aliases were generated, reloaded postfix, and sent a test message, which generated an unknown user bounce.

This lead me to check by creating a new list and testing it. Same message.

The list address is translated to an `@localhost`, which I understand is normal, and the generated aliases include `@localhost`.

I'm not really sure how to move forward. Any thoughts?

Here's the output of `postconf -n`:

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 5s
default_process_limit = 20
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = domain.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, <public ip>, <internal ip>
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mydestination, lists.virtualdomain.org
smtp_connect_timeout = 60s
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 5s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
smtp_host_lookup = dns, native
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: unused parameter: local_recipent_maps=
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this while searching answers, the ultimate answer was found by slamming my head against things until I died.

I'm a mess and I don't necessarily recall everything I did, but I'm going to try.

I decided to follow the postfix-to-mailman.py route, since the Ubuntu documentation leans heavily that way.

I removed mydestination from relay_domains. I think that was a leftover from something else, or older documentation that I followed at some point. I also removed local_recipient_maps to get rid of that warning. That's been there a while, but felt I'd mention it.

The critical points, I think, were twofold:

The removal of the POSTFIX_STYLE_VIRTUAL_DOMAINS line. Reading other things I suspected that this was only relevant when using postfix as the MTA, and that appears to be correct since (so far) it's working.

Second, removing the relay_recipient_maps line. Again, postfix isn't handling these messages, mailman is.

I think that's about the sum of it.